# dart generic extends of Type issue.. method<T extends dynamic>

Tags: function, generics, dart, types

I'm having a little problem here.. I'm trying to write a generic method of T type that extends from dynamic, but inside it show an error when I call an undefined method.

**Code**:

```dart
List<T> toListOf<T extends dynamic>(dynamic data, String key) {
  return List<T>.from(data[key]?.map((x) => T.fromMap(x)));
}
```

**Image**:

[image]

**Error**:

```
The method 'fromMap' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.

Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fromMap'
```

Any solutions?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore well, I have 4 model classes and each one has the fromMap but it would make no sense if I just extends from one of them!!

Comment: That's right. If every model has an fromMap method , then make an abstract class and make your models extend that class. Then in the function use the abstract class as the type.

Comment: `.fromMap` isn't an instance method; it's a *constructor* (or a static method).  You can't use those generically.  You instead could have `toListOf` take a callback  that invokes the appropriate `.fromMap` constructor.

Comment: @jamesdlin Exactly, the fromMap isn't a method.. it's a factory constructor and can't just do an abstract class then extends of it, I'll try what you suggested above.. THANK YOU!